# Custom Post types and their corresponding theme files

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called 'business_sold' that is not reading archive-business_sold.php but instead is reading index.php.  The custom post type is however, properly reading single-business_sold.php.

This is how I registered the custom post type (initially via a plugin through which single-business_sold.php worked) and then I manually added the following code to functions.php:

```
register_post_type('Business_Sold', array(  'label' => 'Businesses Sold','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),'query_var' => true,'has_archive' => true,'menu_position' => 5,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Businesses Sold',  
  'singular_name' => 'Business Sold',  
  'menu_name' => 'Businesses Sold',  
  'add_new' => 'Add Business Sold',  
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Business Sold',  
  'edit' => 'Edit',  
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Business Sold',  
  'new_item' => 'New Business Sold',  
  'view' => 'View Business Sold',  
  'view_item' => 'View Business Sold',  
  'search_items' => 'Search Businesses Sold',  
  'not_found' => 'No Businesses Sold Found',  
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Businesses Sold Found in Trash',  
  'parent' => 'Parent Business Sold',  
),) );
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Is the post type registered with 'has_archive' set to true?

Comment: Yes it is - I did check that before I posted my question.  Any other thoughts, please?

Comment: Are slugs case-sensitive with respect to the template hierarchy? You've registered `Business_Sold` as the CPT slug, rather than `business_sold`. So if that slug is case-sensitive, the template hierarchy might be looking for `single-Business_Sold.php`, rather than `single-business_sold.php`.

Answer (score 1):

When you register custom post in functions.php add this `'has_archive' => 'book-list'`
and then your archive-business_sold.php will work
See this article for details http://www.wpmods.com/wordpress-3-1-custom-post-type-archives

Or just use plugin (for example http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-custom-post-type-archives)